# How do I write jQuery Code inside Racket?

Tags: jquery, html, racket

I want to implement jQuery Code in my Racket application. However I am having syntax troubles. The following is an excerpt from my current testing page:

```
define (render-test-page request)
(local [(define (response-generator make-url) 
        (response/xexpr
         `(html (head (title "Landing Page")
                ;; jquery testing
                (script ((src "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js")))


                (body ...
```

At this point I am not sure how to properly enter a jQuery script so that Racket successfully converts it to the correct HTML code. The current HTML code that Racket generates looks like so:

```
<html><head><title>Landing Page</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head><body>...
```

How do I proceed from here? Let's say I want to test  a simple script like:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
      $("#test").hide();
    });
  });
</script>
```

How would I enter this into the Racket code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably best off putting the jquery in a .js file, and adding the script in the same fashion as before. Generally speaking, it's better practice to organize scripts in this way anyway. Just make sure you add set the path of the .js file correctly.

Comment: I think I will try this. Accepting this after I've successfully figured it out :)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you might find Racket's [web-server/templates](http://docs.racket-lang.org/web-server/templates.html) module useful.